# Stored procedure default not recognize

Tags: sql, sql-server

I get this SQL error:

> expects the parameter '@Site', which was not supplied.

Which means that is expect some kind of value and I am not supplying one. Since `@site` is an optional parameter I set the default to null

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[mySp1]
    (@Site VARCHAR(MAX) = NULL
     .....
```

Yet it is still complaining. Is there a setting I need to turn on or off? Here is how I am calling the stored procedure:

```
exec mySp1 ..... @Site = default
```

Comment: Give us a full [mre], not snippets that imply what you have should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default is applied when argument is ommited:

```
exec mySp1 @otherParam = 1;
```

Or

```
EXEC dbo.mySp1 @Site = DEFAULT;
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=f7b806911a6980314950cf2e32b2a370)**